# How call delegate function without present controller

Tags: swift, swift2

I have Tap Bar Controller with 2 paths. One is `settingController` Other one is `loginController` and `contactListController.
When i run the program the entry pint is set to`contactListController`and if login is false apps shown`loginController`. After login value is set on true and loginController is dismiss. On bottom i have Tab Bar Controller: ContactList | Settings

When i go to settings i have a `LOGOUT` button, i would like to do when i tap this how to set value login  on false ? i have no segue between **ContactList** and **SettingController**

This is my ContactListController

```
class ContactsTableViewController: UITableViewController, SettingsControllerDelegate {

    let settingsController: SettingsController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("settingsController") as! SettingsController

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        settingsController.delegate = self
    }

    func didLogoutSuccessfully() {
        loggedIn = false
    }

}
```

This is settings controller

```
protocol SettingsControllerDelegate {
    func didLogoutSuccessfully()
}

class SettingsController: UITableViewController {
     var delegate: SettingsControllerDelegate?

    fun tapButton() {
        self.delegate?.didLogoutSuccessfully() // Set login as false
    }
```

if i added

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad(
    settingsController.delegate = self
    presentViewController(settingsController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

my controller setting is appear first. How can i change this value in other way?

**UPDATE**
in contact list i have

```
var loggedIn: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            if loggedIn == true {
                self.configureView()
            }
        }
    }

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        if loggedIn == false {
            performSegueWithIdentifier("showLogin", sender: nil)
        }
        //tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: how about you make the bool a shared instance?

Comment: i updated my question

Comment: Why not use NSUserdefaults ?

Comment: User defaults isn't exactly the best place for trusted session info...

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data between the tabs using UITabViewControllers.viewControllers method which returns array of the view controllers in the tab

```
//in SettingsVC
func viewWillDisapear(){
   //assuming its in the second index of tabBar
   let contactVC = self.tabBarController.viewControllers[1] as ContactsTableViewController 
   contactVC.delegate = self
   contactVC.loggedIn = true //or false as you wish
   super.viewWillDisapear() 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider either 1: using notifications (to which all interested controllers are registered as observers) to react to session state changes, 2: moving your session state to something "higher up the chain" (like in or "hanging off of" your app delegate), or 3: making a singleton session controller.

1 can be used with 2 and 3 and either 2 or 3 make accessing the current state from anywhere in your app easier. I'd go with a mix of 1 and 3 myself.

This approach in general relieves you from having to walk and inspect the controller hierarchy to find and set the same thig on all other controllers (which is icky because it's so tightly coupled; changing the hierarchy and/or reusing VCs elsewhere would probably break things).